# How to multiply all the elements inside a list in prolog using recursive rule?

Tags: prolog

These are my facts:

```
%adjroom(Start,End,Key).
adjroom(corridor, room101,17).
adjroom(corridor, room102,3).
adjroom(corridor, room103,5).
adjroom(corridor, room104,20).
adjroom(corridor, store,18).
adjroom(corridor, lift,7).
adjroom(corridor, toilet,11).
adjroom(corridor, kitchen,2).
adjroom(kitchen, laundry,10).
adjroom(lift, lab,13).
```

My question:

A new security policy needs to be implemented. With the new policy, the robot access to the rooms must be controlled. To implement this policy, each robot has a number ID indicating the rooms the robot can access. The rationale to obtain the ID number for a given set of rooms is the following: the ID number is obtained by multiplying all the key codes of the rooms that the robot needs to access. For example, to access the kitchen, the toilet and room102 the following ID 2*11*3=66 needs to be generated (see the Plan of the building for the code associated with each room). Write a PROLOG rule that given a set of rooms generates the ID associated with it.

This is my rule :

```
rr([ ]).

rr([Y,Y2|T]):-adjroom(X,Y,Z),adjroom(X2,Y2,Z2), Q is Z * Z2, print(Q),rr([Y2|T]).
```

Comment: Please format your question and code using the tools available. It is very hard to read without proper formatting.

Comment: seems like you know the basic syntax. Why don't you try to implement the logic? Could require less time than posting on SO, hoping for someone else solving your assignment...

Comment: I do not have enough knowledge on this language as I am a beginner. Any assistance would be appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

Prolog arithmetic it's a bit cumbersome. Say you have a list of numbers, you will need (at least) a 2 argument predicate to get the multiplication done:

```
multiply_list([N], N).
multiply_list([N|Ns], M) :-
  multiply_list(Ns, T), M is N * T.
```

Mapping a list of rooms to a list of numbers can be done with maplist/3, or findall/3

HTH